# Reroute import pathes in django

Tags: python, django, git-submodules

I want to use a django app (newapp) in my django project. To keep it simply updated, I would like to include it as git submodule, but this will lead to a folder structure like:

```
myproject
|-app
|-newapp-git
  |-newapp
    |-settings.py
    |-urls.py
    |-...
  |-README.md
```

That is because, newapp is unfortuntely not only the appfolder but also some files (like readme) and the subfolder newapp. I can add this in `INSTALLED_APPS` with `newapp-git.newapp`, but the app itself imports models etc. with `import newapp` which does not work, and I cannot change it because I dont want to modify the content in newapp to keep it updated simply.

So, is there a chance to tell django, that imports from `newapp` should be rerouted to `newapp-git.newapp`?

Comment: it seems, that I could solve this by just adding symlink from /newapp to newapp-git/newapp..

Comment: Warning. A symlink isn't going to work out well if you want to have a local and production system. Keeping track of it is going to be extremely messy.

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII why? of course its set relative, so what could be the problem?

Comment: in the case where you have the code on multiple machines, you are going to have to constantly keep up and setup symlinks, and based on scaling or any other issues, its probably going to be a headache. But thats also just my opinion.